# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.0.0 Console not reachable after start

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

finished WSO2 installation and first time I start the service and try to log into the management console it's not accessible (hosted on a Amazon EC2 unix instance).

Based on the log file the server starts normally:

```
[2017-03-31 22:40:29,622] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8243/carbon/
```

When I try logging into mgt console the browser is hang up and won't finish loading the page. On wso2carbon.log I get the log entries below:

```
[2017-03-31 22:42:51,456] [EI-Core]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-03-31 22:42:51,457] [EI-Core]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045 - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Mar 31 22:43:21 UTC 2017
[2017-03-31 22:43:44,246] [EI-Core]  INFO - SourceHandler Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2017-03-31 22:43:44,247] [EI-Core]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/179.212.90.90:4529
[2017-03-31 22:45:51,671] [EI-Core]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045
[2017-03-31 22:45:51,672] [EI-Core]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-03-31 22:45:51,672] [EI-Core]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045 - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Mar 31 22:46:21 UTC 2017
[2017-03-31 22:46:44,662] [EI-Core]  INFO - SourceHandler Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2017-03-31 22:46:44,663] [EI-Core]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : 179.212.90.90/179.212.90.90:4592
[2017-03-31 22:48:52,151] [EI-Core]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045
[2017-03-31 22:48:52,151] [EI-Core]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-03-31 22:48:52,151] [EI-Core]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:37045 - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Mar 31 22:49:22 UTC 2017
```

XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the local host IP. YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY is my local IP from where I am trying to connect to the Amazon instance.

I am just trying to open mgt console but it seems the ESB is trying to process my request as a regular endpoint request.

The most confusing piece is that I can open the Analytics dashboard (on 9444) and BPEL mgt console (on 9445) that ships inside EI 6.0.0. Only the Enterprise Integrator mgt console accessible under 8243 port is not reachable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

During login into EI console (ESB+DSS+AS console on 8243 port) EI trying to connect some other services. In my cases I've got (in some installations) Name Notification error at this point.
In your case you received timeout. Probably these port (37045) is closed for IP  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Try to configure AWS Security Group to open this port